# Redmine 500 Internal Error

Tags: redmine

Internal error 500 thrown when I try to navigate through Redmine. I have googled error and found some clues but none helped.

I was following this set up guide to install redmine. You can find it [HERE](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_2_integrated_with_Gitolite_2_on_Debian_Wheezy_with_Apache_and_Phusion_Passenger)

Error looks like this:

> Internal error
>
> An error occurred on the page you were trying to access. If you
>   continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine
>   administrator for assistance.
>
> If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details
>   about the error.
>
> Back

Answer (score 2):

Solved by doing this :

> Step 8 - File system permissions¶
>
> NB: Windows users can skip this section.
>
> The user account running the application must have write permission on
>   the following subdirectories:
>
> files (storage of attachments) log (application log file
>   production.log) tmp and tmp/pdf (create these ones if not present,
>   used to generate PDF documents among other things)
>   public/plugin_assets (assets of plugins) E.g., assuming you run the
>   application with a redmine user account:
>
> mkdir -p tmp tmp/pdf public/plugin_assets sudo chown -R
>   redmine:redmine files log tmp public/plugin_assets sudo chmod -R 755
>   files log tmp public/plugin_assets Step 9 - Test the installation Test
>   the installation by running WEBrick web server:
>
> with Redmine 1.4.x: ruby script/server webrick -e production with
>   Redmine 2.x: ruby script/rails server webrick -e production Once
>   WEBrick has started, point your browser to http://:3000/. You
>   should now see the application welcome page.
>
> Note: Webrick is not suitable for production use, please only use
>   webrick for testing that the installation up to this point is
>   functional. Use one of the many other guides in this wiki to setup
>   redmine to use either Passenger (aka mod_rails), FCGI or a Rack server
>   (Unicorn, Thin, Puma, hellip;) to serve up your redmine.